# Do indefinite quadratic forms have a non trivial root?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, roots, quadratic-forms

Suppose I have a symmetric matrix $A$, and $A$ is neither positive definite nor negative definite.
So, can we say that the quadratic form $x^{T}Ax$ has a non trivial root? i.e. other than $x=0$?

I looked up [Non-trivial kernel if quadratic form is indefinite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1541749/non-trivial-kernel-if-quadratic-form-is-indefinite) this post but the reasoning is quite unclear to me.
Can anyone help?

Comment: The answer is yes, as the posted answer indicates

Answer (score 1):

According to a theorem of Sylvester there exists a base change, i.e. an invertible matrix $S$, such that $D:=S^tAS$ is diagonal and the diagonal elements are in the set $\{-1,0,1\}$. If $A$ is indefinite two cases can appear:

1. At least one $0$ appears among the diagonal elements. Hence $e_k^tDe_k=0$ for some standard basis vector, which gives $x:=Se_k$ as a non-trivial 'root'.
2. $1$ and $-1$ appear as diagonal elements. Hence $e^tDe=0$ for a certain vector $e$ having exactly one coordintae equal to 1 and exactly one coordintae equal to -1. Again $Se$ then is a non-trivial 'root'.